# C++ Adding values to kind of a matrix

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, crash

I have the following class:

```
class clsJoinFeeder
{
public:
    vector<vector<unsigned char> > UnsignedChars;
};
```

Now I would like to add a vector of unsigned chars to the class.
I tried to do it like this:

```
void CBinLoader::LoadJoinFeaturesFromCompiledDat(clsJoinFeeder &uJoinFeeder)
{
    for (unsigned int y=0;y<2;y++)
    {
        for (unsigned int x=0;x<17;x++)
        {
            pLoadSmallFloatMap(uJoinFeeder);
            pLoadBigUnsignedCharMap(uJoinFeeder);
        }
    }
}

void CBinLoader::pLoadBigUnsignedCharMap(clsJoinFeeder &uJoinFeeder)
{
    unsigned int iItemsCount = 0;
    fread(&iItemsCount,sizeof(unsigned int),1,m_infile);

    unsigned long iByteSizeActualData = 0;
    fread(&iByteSizeActualData,sizeof(unsigned long),1,m_infile);

    vector<unsigned char>nChars;
    nChars.resize(iItemsCount+1);

    fread(&nChars[0],iByteSizeActualData,1,m_infile); //works fine. nChars is correctly filled

    uJoinFeeder.UnsignedChars.push_back(nChars); //here the crash occurs
}
```

It compiles fine, but at runtime it crashes with a heap alloc error in the line:

```
uJoinFeeder.UnsignedChars.push_back(nChars);
```

What can I do to resolve the problem? I don't even see my mistake.

Edit:

Thank you for the help!
"iByteSizeActualData" was wrong as Mr. Kühl stated.

Comment: Where is the argument `uJoinFeeder` ultimately defined? Is the value by any chance a global variable which is possibly not, yet, initialized?

Comment: Try to insert a simple vector into `uJoinFeeder.UnsignedChars` and see if it works

Comment: @Kunal Wow, that works. Let me check what the difference is...

Comment: It was my fault... "iByteSizeActualData" is wrong. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @tmighty No need to delete the question. You can add an edit stating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `iItemsCount` and `iByteSizeActualData` have different values with the latter being bigger than `iItemsCount`. Personally, I would invoke `fread()` as

```
if (fread(&nChars[0], nChars.size(), 1, m_infile) != nChars.size()) {
    dealWithTheError();
}
```

(well, I wouldn't call `fread()` but rather `stream.read()` but this is a different matter).

Comment: @tmight: OK... Where is `myJoinFeeder` defined? Is it properly initialized by the time the vector is pushed to the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myJoinFeeder.UnsignedChars.push_back(std::vector<unsigned char>(std::begin(nChars), std::end(nChars));
```

Comment: wouldn't be `myJoinFeeder.UnsignedChars.insert(myJoinFeeder.UnsignedChars.end(), nChars.begin(), nChars.end())` better? I doubt your example will even compile.

Comment: @Marius: no, probably not: it seems, the user wants to insert a sequence of vectors rather than transforming the sequence of `char`s into a sequence of vectors sized by the [possibly negative] value of the `char`s.

Comment: Both do not work, but thank you. The same heap alloc error occurs.

Comment: @tmighty Is there some more relevant code? Maybe the error is somewhere else.